# MoveByModifier does not reset Andengine

Tags: android, andengine, modifier

I am trying to make a sprite move using MoveByModifier in Andengine. I want it to keep repeating after the modifier has finished but i am unable to achieve that. Following is my code if anyone can help...

```
MoveByModifier mod1 = new MoveByModifier(20, 150, 400){
        @Override
        protected void onModifierFinished(IEntity pItem) {
            super.reset(); 
        }
    };

Sprite.registerEntityModifier(mod1);
mMainScene.attachChild(Sprite);
```

I also tried LoopEntityModifier but still it does not repeat... I cant understand why?

```
Sprite.registerEntityModifier(new LoopEntityModifier(mod1));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want repeating moving sprite from start position, you can use

```
MoveModifier mod1 = new MoveModifier(20,Sprite.getX(), Sprite.getY(), Sprite.getX()+150, Sprite.getY()+400);
Sprite.registerEntityModifier(new LoopEntityModifier(mod1));
```

Repeating `MoveByModifier` continues moving from current coordinates.

Comment: The syntax of the move modifier u have given is incorrect. Its MoveModifier(duration, fromX, toX, fromY, toY).. anyway it helped me.. thanks

Comment: `public MoveModifier(final float pDuration, final float pFromX, final float pFromY, final float pToX, final float pToY)` https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine/blob/GLES2-AnchorCenter/src/org/andengine/entity/modifier/MoveModifier.java

Comment: `public MoveModifier(final float pDuration, final float pFromX, final float pToX, final float pFromY, final float pToY)` in old vesion AndEngine

Comment: oh ok... the version i have... which is gles2 only has the type public MoveModifier(final float pDuration, final float pFromX, final float pToX, final float pFromY, final float pToY)

Answer (score 0):

No need to reset the modifier after finish it.You have to remove  **super.reset();** inside **onModifierFinished** method. Because when you call this, it removes the applied modifier from the Sprite.

For repeating the sprite from old postion to new one, write like

```
  MoveModifier moveModifier= new MoveModifier(20,Sprite.getX(), Sprite.getY(), Sprite.getX()+150, Sprite.getY()+400);
Sprite.registerEntityModifier(new LoopEntityModifier(moveModifier));
```